# Pgfplots not plotting bar graph with all symbolic coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create a bar graph using pgfplots. Specifically, I have 8 different bins of varying signal length against some computational time. I have set the x axis signal lengths to symbolic coordinates and have those plotted against time. The resultant graph however, does not seem to plot the last "*bin*" of times (i.e signal length of 32768).

I have the code attached below:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\Dshadowbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=\textbf{Computation Time} $\mathbf{s}$,
    xlabel=\textbf{Signal Length $\mathbf{N}$},
    xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords = {256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768},
    ybar interval=0.8,
    xtick={256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768},
    bar width = 10pt,
    ymode=log,
    bar shift=0pt,
    log origin=infty,
    width=\textwidth
        ]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(256,0.0202) (512,0.0445)
         (1024,0.1578) (2048,0.5877)  (4096,3.5797) (8192,18.8230) (16384,103.7727) (32768,762.0937)};

\addplot
    coordinates {(256,0.0012) (512,0.0034) 
        (1024,0.0106) (2048,0.0229) (4096,0.1045) (8192,0.4693) (16384,3.0236) (32768,22.8810)};

\addplot
    coordinates {(256,0.0009) (512,0.0013) 
        (1024,0.0027) (2048,0.0059) (4096,0.220) (8192,0.0858) (16384,0.3697) (32768,3.7458)};

\addplot
    coordinates {(256,0.0028) (512,0.0032) 
        (1024,0.0052) (2048,0.0168) (4096,0.0638) (8192,0.2927) (16384,1.4904) (32768,9.21)};

\addplot 
    coordinates {(256,0.0011) (512,0.0019) 
        (1024,0.0085) (2048,0.0486) (4096,0.1973) (8192,0.6917) (16384,3.2107) (32768,17.1235)};

\addplot 
    coordinates {(256,0.00006) (512,0.00014) 
        (1024,0.00022) (2048,0.00047) (4096,0.0019) (8192,0.0085) (16384,0.3123) (32768,5.9074)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

I'm sure I have made a silly error somewhere but haven't been able to see it as of yet. Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra coordinates for each `addplot`, since `ybar interval=0.8` is used;  therefore 8 coordinates only generates 7 `ybar` because an interval is defined by two coordinates. The last coordinate will only be used to determine the interval width; its y value doesn't change the bar appearance. Here (65536,0.1) is appended as a dummy coordinate to serve as the horizontal end point. Since the OP did not provide `\Dshadowbox`, it is therefore disable to make a run.

As a side note, if `ybar interval=0.8` is removed, (that is no ybar interval plot) then the last coordinate (32768,y) will show.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}



\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}[htbp]
%\centering
%\Dshadowbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=\textbf{Computation Time} $\mathbf{s}$,
    xlabel=\textbf{Signal Length $\mathbf{N}$},
    xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords = {256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536},
    ybar interval=0.8,
    xtick={256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536},
    bar width = 10pt,
    ymode=log,
    bar shift=0pt,
    log origin=infty,
    width=\textwidth
        ]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(256,0.0202) (512,0.0445)
         (1024,0.1578) (2048,0.5877)  (4096,3.5797) (8192,18.8230) (16384,103.7727) (32768,762.0937)(65536,0.1)};

\addplot
    coordinates {(256,0.0012) (512,0.0034) 
        (1024,0.0106) (2048,0.0229) (4096,0.1045) (8192,0.4693) (16384,3.0236) (32768,22.8810)(65536,0.1)};

\addplot
    coordinates {(256,0.0009) (512,0.0013) 
        (1024,0.0027) (2048,0.0059) (4096,0.220) (8192,0.0858) (16384,0.3697) (32768,3.7458)(65536,0.1)};

\addplot
    coordinates {(256,0.0028) (512,0.0032) 
        (1024,0.0052) (2048,0.0168) (4096,0.0638) (8192,0.2927) (16384,1.4904) (32768,9.21)(65536,0.1)};

\addplot 
    coordinates {(256,0.0011) (512,0.0019) 
        (1024,0.0085) (2048,0.0486) (4096,0.1973) (8192,0.6917) (16384,3.2107) (32768,17.1235)(65536,0.1)};

\addplot 
    coordinates {(256,0.00006) (512,0.00014) 
        (1024,0.00022) (2048,0.00047) (4096,0.0019) (8192,0.0085) (16384,0.3123) (32768,5.9074)(65536,0.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```